# Run SQL Server 2000 Job programmatically

Tags: sql-server-2000

I know you can execute a Job in SQL Server 2005/2008 by sending a call to the Stored Procedure msdb.dbo.sp_start_job.

However is it possible to do this programmatically for SQL Server 2000?

I am using VB.NET however I believe the language I'm using is irrelevant on how to go about it.

If someone knows how to do it in VB.NET (or C#, I can convert it), I'd appreciate it.

Edit: Appears it does exist in 2000. I couldn't locate it in Management Studio, MSDN for the 2005 "Other Versions" link only had 2005 and 2008, and google was only bringing up the 2005 version. Sorry for wasting people's time!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260289(SQL.80).aspx

Suggests that sp_start_job is supported in SQL Server 2000

Comment: Wow, google failed me. I was at the MSDN for it on the 2005, and clicked "Other Versions" but it only showed me 2008.

Couldn't find it in any of my other searches. Thanks for finding that for me.

Answer (score 0):

sp_start_job is available in 2000 as well.